# Cant understand what this function does

Tags: python-3.x, stack

def is_balanced(input_str):
s = list()

```
for ch in input_str:
    if ch == '(':
        s.append(ch)
    if ch == ')':
        if not s:
            return False
        s.pop()
return not s
```

Can anyone explain what is really happening after the line "if ch == ')':"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if not s:`
checks whether the list is empty or not, if the list is empty then the condition inside is executed.

let's say you provide `())()()` in input, so for:

-> the 0th index it will first add `(` into `s`

-> for 1st index (i.e `)`): it will first check if `s` is empty or not, as here we have `(` in `s` so the `if` condition will not execute, then it goes on to pop the value from the list. (notice now the list is empty)

-> on coming to the 2nd index (i.e `)`): it will first check if the list is empty or not, as the list is empty it will return `False`

Comment: what is meant by the last line "return not s"?

Comment: @AsifMahmud for a valid input the stack should be empty at the end of the program, i.e for every `)` a `(` should be popped from the stack.
The last line returns `True` if the stack is empty